# Where are VisualBoyAdvance's save files stored?

Tags: emulation, game-boy-advance

I am using the VisualBoyAdvance emulator and I am trying to find the save file location (not the save state location, the one from the actual game.)

The game is Final Fantasy VI if it helps. I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I've corrected "virtual boy advance" to "VisualBoyAdvance." I believe this is the emulator you meant as I can't find any mention of a 'virtual boy advance' emulator by searching the web. If this is incorrect, just edit your question to correct it.

Answer (score 4):

I just tested this one and the save file is located *in the same folder as where your ROM files are*. The extension is **.sav**. A save using VBA, *not in-game*, ends with the extension **.sgm**.

Answer (score 1):

The save files are in your ROMs folder and it has the .sgm extension or the .save extension. They both must have the same name as the ROM to work.

- romname.gba or romname.zip <-- Rom File.
- romname.sgm <-- Quick Save File.
- romname.sav (VBA 1.7.2) or romname.sa1 (VBA 1.7.2 Link) <-- Normal Save File.